# Anyone with PHP skills interested in updating an add-on for EE 5?

Tags: add-on-development, email, spam, encode

[Obscure, (see files on GitHub)](https://github.com/mcfarlandonline/obscure), encodes all content between the tags {exp:obscure}{/exp:obscure} similar to the way the {encode} tag for email works in ExpressionEngine. Add-on provides additional flexibility by allowing you to include other elements or images within the tag. For example:

```
<li>
  {exp:obscure}
    <a href="mailto:megan@netraising.com?subject=I can fix Obscure Add-On">
      <img src="...envelope-icon.svg" alt="Email Megan" />
    </a>
   {/exp:obscure}
</li>
```

Currently this add-on only works in EE version 2 & 3. ☹️

Are there any PHP-savvy folks out there interested in updating this code so it works in ExpressionEngine 5?

Comment: ready for merge

Answer (score 1):

The update is waiting for you. You can take it in [my fork](https://github.com/MaxLazar/obscure) or approved push request which I did for your repo.

p.s. I will do some extra updates this evening because I can see that some unsafe method using - like **$_POST**

Comment: Thanks so much, Max! I really appreciate this!